# LazyTableImages for iPhone Sample Code Reload Question

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am using the LazyTableImages sample code to aynchronusly load images in my table view from an RSS feed. What I would like to know is, how to reload (restart the parsing operation) in this table once a new item has been added, specific to this example?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to request the download over again.  You'll probably want to add a new method to LazyTableAppDelegate that does this, since that's the class that does the initial download:

```
- (void)reloadAppList
{
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:TopPaidAppsFeed]];
    self.appListFeedConnection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self] autorelease];
}
```

Also, modify -[LazyTableAppDelegate handleLoadedApps:] to clear the old data, like this:

```
- (void)handleLoadedApps:(NSArray *)loadedApps
{
    [self.appRecords removeAllObjects];
    rootViewController.entries = [NSArray array];
    [self.appRecords addObjectsFromArray:loadedApps];

    // tell our table view to reload its data, now that parsing has completed
    [rootViewController.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I haven't tried this myself, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the reply. I've tried this and I understand this being the main idea but it crashes, plus modifying handleLoadedApps to clear the objects prevents the RSS feed from loading initially. Any further guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Changing `rootViewController.entries = [NSArray array];` to `[rootViewController.imageDownloadsInProgress removeAllObjects];` in `handleLoadedApps` seems to be working for me. In my case I create a new `NSURLConnection` in `ApplicationWillEnterForeground`

Answer (score 1):

(Cannot find a way to comment...)

I'm having the same issue here and tried this approach. Cleared the appRecords using removeAllObjects, but the second time around, all works for the articles, but the icons do not get loaded.

You can reproduce the issue by changing the original sample code this way:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
```

{
    // Configure and show the window
    [window addSubview:[self.navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

```
// Initialize the array of app records and pass a reference to that list to our root view controller
self.appRecords = [NSMutableArray array];
rootViewController.entries = self.appRecords;
```

// NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:TopPaidAppsFeed]];
   //self.appListFeedConnection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self] autorelease];

```
// Test the validity of the connection object. The most likely reason for the connection object
// to be nil is a malformed URL, which is a programmatic error easily detected during development
// If the URL is more dynamic, then you should implement a more flexible validation technique, and
// be able to both recover from errors and communicate problems to the user in an unobtrusive manner.
//
//NSAssert(self.appListFeedConnection != nil, @"Failure to create URL connection.");

// show in the status bar that network activity is starting
// [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
[self reloadData];
```

}

- (IBAction)reload:(id)sender {
  [self reloadData];
  }

-(void)reloadData {
    NSLog(@"Updating entries");
    [self.appRecords removeAllObjects];
    //[[myTableViewController imageDownloadsInProgress] removeAllObjects];

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:TopPaidAppsFeed]];
self.appListFeedConnection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self] autorelease];

// Test the validity of the connection object. The most likely reason for the connection object
// to be nil is a malformed URL, which is a programmatic error easily detected during development
// If the URL is more dynamic, then you should implement a more flexible validation technique, and
// be able to both recover from errors and communicate problems to the user in an unobtrusive manner.
//
NSAssert(self.appListFeedConnection != nil, @"Failure to create URL connection.");

// show in the status bar that network activity is starting
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
```

}